# bizarre CSS issue - text in <a> tags gets "pushed down"

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having a bizarre problem.

On my page, http://radiovalerie.org/ - text that's wrapped in a hyperlink tag gets pushed down slightly, as if it has some extra "line-height" property applied to it, but I have no clue where this property is being called from in the CSS.

Example: "Listen via → iTunes • Winamp • WindowsMedia" on the right hand side of the page.
The "Listen via" part is normal, but once the hyperlinks start coming after it, it's almost as if they have a different line-height.

I've combed the website's .css file directly, as well as snooped through the code using Chrome's element inspector, but I can't seem to track down the culprit which makes hyperlinked text look slightly off.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I have an idea - post the relevant code here. I did try to visit your site, but it doesn't support IE full stop!

Comment: In FireFox your links are slightly higher than the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reset.css line 20 includes

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

When I cancelled this line in the Safari element inspector, the text in question jumped back in line with the "Listen via...".

You could override this by adding

```
vertical-align: top;
```

into style.css, in the block that starts on line 166.

The original problem is likely to be caused by a difference in the height of the standard text in that font vs the height of the `<a>` element with the reset css applied.

Answer (score 2):

On line 20 of your `reset.css` you have

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

That's why the text is being pushed.

Simple remove it or change to `top` on your links.

Answer (score 0):

In FireFox, the links show slightly *higher* than the text.  Disabling the bottom padding o the a tag in style.css smoves them back down to even with the text.

In Chrome, disabling `vertical-align: middle` from reset.css seems to fix the problem.  That seems like an odd setting for a css reset.  This same change also fixes the display in FireFox without changing the padding.

Considering the number of small differences in the display between Chrome and FireFox, you might want to consider a different CSS Reset.